# Algorithms to estimate eigenvectors in Perron–Frobenius theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ positive matrix: $ a_{{ij}}>0$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$. According to the statement of [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Statement_of_the_Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem), one of the claims is
$$\lim _{{k\rightarrow \infty }}A^{k}/r^{k}=vw^{T}\,,\quad \tag{1}$$ 
where the left and right eigenvectors for A are normalized so that $w^Tv = 1$. The positive real number $r$ is called the Perron root.

I would like to know whether there exist some algorithm to estimate the eigenvectors in Eq. (1) e what are they.

Thanks in advance.